# Rails - image.png Isn't Precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline, precompiled

I'm attempting to deploy a web application on Amazon's EC2 servers, and I have the code up on the server. Everything looks like it's working, but when I go to the home page, I get a 500 error message and the `production.log` file gives me the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (image.png isn't precompiled)
```

- I've tried running `rake assets:precompile`,
- I've changed the line in `config/environments/production.rb` to `config.assets.compile = true`
- I've checked that the compiled `image.png` is in `public/assets/manifest.yml`

but I still get the same error.

I'm running Rails 3.2.6 and Ruby 1.8.7.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does public/assets/image.png exist?

Comment: Yes. (more characters to make SO happy)

Comment: Can you try running `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` maybe?

Comment: That fixed it - I guess it defaults to precompiling only in the development environment? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` should fix it.
If you don't provide any `RAILS_ENV`, Rails assumes it's `development`

I believe that's because each env in the asset pipeline behaves differently. Therefore, as a general rule, in production, always run rake tasks with RAILS_ENV='production' and you should stay safe.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Openshift from Redhat and when deployed on the server it RAKEs to the production environment automatically.  I too had the same problem but only on the production server.

Performing the change:

config/environments/production.rb to config.assets.compile = true

worked a treat.   There is another parameter in this file vou could change:

config.assets.precompile += %w[ *.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.gif ]

When deployed on the server you could then do manually:

rake RAILS_ENV=production

or if you are using a server like Openshift that deploys automatically, configurations in the production.rb file will be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

In `config/application.rb` add a line like:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['image.png']
```

Although, if its in `public/assets/images` you shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - needed to run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV='production` instead of just `rake assets:precompile` ...